# Mechanical Engineering undergrad aspiring to publish

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I'm an undergraduate student of Mechanical Engineering, now closing my third year of studies. Throughout the years however, I've always went a bit off coursework to study and research the area. By now I have some material that I believe it could be publishable, and I would like to work towards that goal.

Although my entire research is a bit spread, I have something specific in mind that I would like to try and publish and that is a study on optimal beam profiles. My question is, which would be the best journal to submit? I researched some on Elsevier but they seemed too professional to me.

In total, what would be the best journal to try and submit work that is analytical in nature, but related to mechanical engineering?

Comment: First, I would talk to someone at your department. They probably can help you much better than we can.

Comment: Trust me dude, I tried that. They will not allow undergraduate papers on the local journal. Honestly, all I want is a blind review process. Would be best for me.

Comment: Oh, there was a missunderstanding: Ask them where to send your work. Maybe they can even read it and make suggestions.